# Facebook OAuth error: Error validating verification code

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-apps, restfb

I'm trying to get the access token for Facebook login, but got an error instead. All the answers that I found tell me about the wrong redirect_uri format.
This is the error I got:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "Ht12b5BKgRK"
   }
}
```

And here is the redirect URI registered in Facebook App.
[image]

Steps that I do:

1. https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyProject/Mapping&scope=user_posts&response_type=code
2. This link redirect me to http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyProject/Mapping?code=GENERATED_CODE
3. Then in the code i generate next URI:
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=549422435210997&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyProject/Mapping&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=GENERATED_CODE
4. Requesting this URI gives me error instead of `access_token`

I have tryied also `redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyProject/Mapping/`. Still no results.

Also, I have tied the same steps using restFB library for Java. And got the same error.

```
ScopeBuilder scopeBuilder = new ScopeBuilder();
scopeBuilder.addPermission(UserDataPermissions.USER_POSTS);
FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.LATEST);
String loginDialogUrlString = client.getLoginDialogUrl(APP_ID, "http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyProject/Mapping", scopeBuilder);
System.out.println(loginDialogUrlString);

System.out.println();
AccessToken appAccessToken = client.obtainAppAccessToken(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);
System.out.println(appAccessToken.getAccessToken());
System.out.println(appAccessToken.getTokenType());

//On this step i got the same error
AccessToken userAccessToken = client.obtainUserAccessToken(APP_ID, APP_SECRET, "http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyProject/Mapping/", appAccessToken.getAccessToken());
System.out.println(userAccessToken.getAccessToken());
```

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that bit me when I did this is to make sure that the redirect_uri is URL encoded.  In Java my code did something like:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

URLEncoder.encode("http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyProject/Mapping", "UTF-8")
```

for my redirect URL.  Don't encode the entire URL, just the portion that is your redirect_uri.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have tried to encode the URL, and still got no results.

Comment: This is encoded URL, which gieves me the same error in browser: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2FMyProject%2FMapping%2F&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET

Comment: When I try to implement it the code I got `redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986. (code 191, subcode null)`